# Null/Empty DateTimePicker when cellclicked to a null date in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datetimepicker

I have a Datagridview which is DGV and there's a column name Drop Date(it's for students who dropped the subject) and I have some null cells in there. As the title says, I want the DateTimePicker to be null when clicked on a null cell.

Here's my code.

```
   Private Sub DGV_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGV.CellClick
        If DGV.CurrentRow.Cells(6).Value Is Nothing Then
            DTP.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
            DTP.CustomFormat = " "
        Else
            DTP.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short
            DTP.Text = DGV.CurrentRow.Cells(6).Value.ToString
        End If
   End Sub
```

Here's the problem.

When I 1st clicked on a cell that has a value and then 2nd clicked on the cell without value, it still show the value of the 1st clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Already fixed it.

```
       If String.IsNullOrEmpty(DGV.CurrentRow.Cells(6).Value.ToString) = True Then
            DTP.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
            DTP.CustomFormat = " "
        Else
            DTP.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short
            DTP.Text = DGV.CurrentRow.Cells(6).Value.ToString
        End If
```